# Как правильно употреблять словосочетание "световой год"?

Tags: падежи

На расстоянии четыре световых года от нас.
На расстоянии четырех световых лет от нас.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **На расстоянии**  (каком?) **четырех световых лет от нас.**

Или: **на расстоянии в четыре световых года**.

Несогласованное определение, выраженное количественно-именным оборотом в  форме беспредложного Р.п. или в форме В.п. с предлогом.

Существительное "расстояние" управляет Р.п., а само расстояние может измеряться в любых единицах.

Пример: Какой-то идиот построил её на расстоянии четырёх километров от ближайшего водоёма. [Сергей Довлатов. Заповедник (1983)]

Comment: *Несогласованное определение, выраженное количественно-именным оборотом* - Ну да, оно самое. Только вопрос-то не в том, каким словом его обозвать, а каким падежом управляют слова "на расстоянии". У Довлатова-то правильно, вопросов нет, но  почему?! Чтобы ссылка была на правило. Я не нашел, только примеры.

Comment: Из словаря: РАССТОЯНИЕ, -я; ср. . На расстоянии  метра, вытянутой руки. Р. в тысячу лет отделяет нас от крещения Руси Пройти р. в пять километров.   Таким образом, возможны два варианта: на расстоянии пяти километров и на расстоянии в пять километров

Comment: А не "светов**ых**"?

Comment: Да, да, как раз хотела исправить.

Comment: "Из словаря" не прокатит.  "Расстояние" и "на расстоянии"  требуют ***разных***  падежей. У Розенталя есть упоминание о беспредложном управлении "на расстоянии", но он, зараза, там цифрами пишет....

Comment: Нет никаких сомнений, что "на расстоянии"  требует Р.п. , этой формой пользовались все классики: Эта встреча произошла на расстоянии десяти сажень огромной залы,  [А. С. Грин. (1923)]  Две секунды, и лица, на расстоянии двух аршин,  уже промелькнули, [Л. Н. Толстой. Отрочество (1854)] А форма В.п. "в пять километров" используется во всех случаях: расстояние (И.п.)  в пять километров. с расстояния  (Р.п.) в пять километров, на расстоянии (П.п.) в пять километров и т.д.

Comment: @Sibylla, А что вы хотите доказать приводя цитаты из классиков? Я же не возражаю, что классики пользовались. Вы просто не можете  сформулировать и ссылки дать на **правило**, вместо этого отсылаете к словарю, где нет даже упоминания нужной форме.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос и простой, и не очень...

Ясно, что *"На расстоянии" (чего?)* требует родительного падежа. Ссылку на авторитетный источник дать могу, но вот хотя бы такое.

> Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать следующую
>   фразу (1410 словами используя правильные падежи): На расстоянии в 1410
>   километров из Симферополя в Москву мы останавливались три раза.
>
> По дороге в Москву мы останавливались три раза на расстоянии одной
>   тысячи четырехсот десяти километров от Симферополя.

http://nekin.info/math/imya_chislitelnoye.htm

В профессиональной речи часто родительный заменяют винительным (или именительным? - "на расстоянии сколько?"), но это ошибка.

То есть у вас вроде бы получится ***"На расстоянии четырех световых лет от нас."***

Но тут есть сложность. "Лет" или "годов"? Ведь использование счетной формы "лет" для слова "год" справедливо только для единицы времени, в отношении единицы расстояния "световой год" это далеко не очевидно.

Более того, астрономы тяготеют именно к такому варианту, "годов". 
Поэтому, если материал предназначен для профессиональной целевой аудитории, то порекомендую ***"На расстоянии четырех световых годов от нас."***

А если издание научно-популярное или художественное, то смело оставьте "лет".

И еще. Если единица там дробная, то всегда - "года". Даже в беллетристике.

***На расстоянии 3,4 (=трех целых и четырех десятых) года.***

Добавлю.

1.
Поскольку совершенно неожиданно возникло возражение (у Sibylla - в пересказе), даю суть проблемы.

"Лет" это счетная форма к слову "год". Использование её зависит от падежа и контекста.

И. Однн год, два года, пять лет/годов.
Р. Одного года, двух лет/годов, пяти лет/годов.
Д. Одному года, двум годам, пяти годам.
В. Один года, два года, пять лет/годов.
Т. Одним годом, двумя годами, пятью годами.
П. (об) Одном годе, двух годах, пяти годах.

В тех случаях, когда стоит лет/годов - первая форма используется для обозначения промежутка времени, вторая - для списка из номеров (*"пять **годов** - 1905, 19017, 1941, 1945, 1991 - имеют особое значение для русской истории"*).

2. Что же касается сочетания "световой год", то это самостоятельная счетная единица - и нет никаких оснований полагать, что к ней обязательно применимо то же правило. По моим наблюдением в научной литературе чаще используется форма "годов" - "Пять световых годов" - даже в именительном, родительном и винительном падежах.

Я не предлагаю её использовать в детской, скажем, литературе (хотя и надо бы, но устоялось иное). Но в профессиональной среде - только так.

Что же касается ссылки на словарь, то там вообще нет указания на падеж при беспредложном управлении сочетания *"на расстоянии [пять единиц]"*, хотя понятно, что оно может отличаться управления просто "расстояние".

Тут дело такое. Беспредложное сочетание типа "на расстоянии пять единиц" развилось в профессиональной речи сравнительно недавно. Исходной формой было "на расстоянии **в** пять единиц". (см. Розенталь)

Две ссылки:
[Аррениус (астроном)](https://books.google.ru/books?id=U-whBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%22&source=bl&ots=SsClHy9M3l&sig=-d4JBwS3typhFG0tg5j1jCt5im4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQgJ_v7qHUAhUBKpoKHRL4B6wQ6AEIRzAH#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%22&f=false) - пример использования
И
[Розенталь](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlv.html) - о беспредложном управлении, к сожалению нет явного указания на падеж. Но можно по аналогии заключить, что там родительный.

> Беспредложные конструкции, появившиеся сначала в
>   профессионально-технической речи, получили в некоторых случаях широкое
>   распространение, например: глубиной пятнадцать метров, шириной три
>   метра, на высоте 4500 метров, ценой четыре миллиона рублей, стоимостью
>   пятьдесят долларов, ростом 170 сантиметров, мощностью 100 тысяч
>   киловатт, водоизмещением 30 тысяч тонн, массой два килограмма, со
>   скоростью шестьдесят километров в час, на расстоянии 425 километров,
>   тиражом 50 тысяч экземпляров, водохранилище объёмом 185 миллионов
>   кубометров и т. п. (без предлога в).

Но сомнения остаются, поскольку пример дается в ряду, где используется и очевидный винительный падеж.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59860/discussion-on-answer-by------).

Comment: Поскольку с водой выплеснули и ребенка, восстановлю содержательное. @Alex_ander в технической - нет. А в научной - вполне. В молодости увлекался астрономией, а и до не давнего времени был знаком с астрономами. Крижижановский при всё моем уважении - не фигура.
 Посмотрите еще здесь newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=782. Или попробуйте ответить на вопрос "В чем измерятся расстояние?" Не в световых же летах?! Или уберите слово "расстояние". В четырех световых годах от нас расположена Проксима (Альфа Центавра). - ну никак же не по другому. При чем тут Доминикович и "цифры" два-три-четыре?!

Comment: @Alex_ander А вот и ссылочка нашлась https://books.google.ru/books?id=U-whBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%22&source=bl&ots=SsClHy9M3l&sig=-d4JBwS3typhFG0tg5j1jCt5im4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQgJ_v7qHUAhUBKpoKHRL4B6wQ6AEIRzAH#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%22&f=false

Comment: комментарии не удалены, а перемещены в чат, там вы вполне можете продолжить общение. При необходимости дополнить вопрос, воспользуйтесь функцией редактирования.